# Relational algebra and SQL solving

Tags: sql-server, join

Using the following relations:

```
consultant(id,Name,Skill) 

CustomerCompany(Id,name Address, Phone, Email, WebAddr,Market)

project(id,StartDate,EndDate,ConsultantID,CustomerId,Days)

Invoice(id,Date,Customer,Amount,Status)
```

Im trying to work out the following scenario using SQL and Relational algebra

Find the names of the consultants and the names of customers, where the consultant has worked for the customer, and the customer received  an invoice in the range of GBP 100k to 200k

Using SQL i have:

> Select I.amount, C.name from CustomerCompany C, Invoice I where
>   I.Customer=C.id and >all(select C.name, Con.Name from CustomerCompany, Con Consultant where i.amount
>   between 100 and 200);

Relational algebra:

```
amount = σ(Invoice, amount>=100 and amount<=200)

joininv= Ⓧ(amount, Customer, CustomerCompany, id)

joincon Ⓧ(joiniv, Consultant id, Project, ConsultantID)

π =(joincon, name, Name)
```

I was wondering if write or wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hardly anyone outside of Academia/Research uses or is proficient with Relational Algebra (almost 30 years since I've used it).  You will probably get a better response at http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the Trick

```
select 
con.Name
from CustomerCompany CustComp
inner join project PRO on PRO.CustomerId=CustComp.Id
inner join consultant con on con.id=PRO.ConsultantID
inner join Invoice Inv on Inv.Customer=CustComp.name
where Inv.Amount between 100 and 200
```

**[JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)**