# Joining between several tables

Tags: sql, database, join

My question is about SQL queries

using the following tables:

```
1. consultant(id,Name,Skill) 
2. CustomerCompany(Id,name Address, Phone, Email, WebAddr,Market)
3. project(id,StartDate,EndDate,ConsultantID,CustomerId,Days)
4. Invoice(id,Date,Customer,Amount,Status)
```

what is the SQL statement for

find the names of the consultants that worked for customers in Berlin and London

i think you have to join the tables but i cant a definite query, any suggestions?

Comment: What flavor of SQL is this? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Didn't you just doubled your own question? :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466400/relational-algebra-and-sql-solving

Comment: It's unclear because you do not have a specific City field (your Table CustomerCompany indicates only composite Address field, which may contain multiple address data items, so you may end up with LIKE (*BERLIN*) clause.

Comment: sql and no its a different query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT C.Name
FROM Consultant C
--Join on projects the consultant worked on
JOIN Project P ON P.ConsultantID = C.ConsultantID
--Join on the customer companies those projects were for
JOIN CustomerCompany CC ON CC.ID = P.CustomerID
--Addresses might have various formats, use the LIKE operator
WHERE CC.Address LIKE '%London%' OR CC.Address LIKE '%Berlin%'
```

might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
con.Name
from CustomerCompany CustComp
inner join project PRO on PRO.CustomerId=CustComp.Id
inner join consultant con on con.id=PRO.ConsultantID
where CustComp.Address LIKE '%London%' OR CustComp.Address LIKE '%Berlin%'
```

**[JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Very little can be determined from your question but you could do something like this:

```
 SELECT Name from consultant c
 join CustomerCompany cc on c.id = cc.id
 WHERE market in ('London', 'Berlin')
```

The basic join is like this

```
 Select columnname from FirstTable alias
 join secondtable alias on fieldFromFirstTable = FieldFromSecondTable
 WHERE criteria.
```